# Partial matching of elements in two string columns in R

Tags: r, string, match, strsplit

I have a large data grouped by two identifiers (Group and ID), `Initial` column that shows in an initial time period, and a `Post` column to show elements that occur following the initial time period.  A working examples is below:

```
SampleDF<-data.frame(Group=c(0,0,1),ID=c(2,2,3),
Initial=c('F28D,G06F','F24J ,'G01N'), 
Post=c('G06F','H02G','F23C,H02G,G01N'))
```

I want to compare elements in `Initial` and `Post` for each `Group/ID` combination to find out when elements match, when only new elements exist, and when both pre-existing and new elements exist. Ideally, I would like to end up with a new `Type` variable with the following output:

```
SampleDF<-cbind(SampleDF, 'Type'=rbind(0,1,2))
```

where (relative to `Initial`) `0` indicates that there are no new element(s) in `Post`, `1` indicates that there are only new element(s) in `Post`, and `2` indicates that there are both pre-existing and new element(s) in `Post`.

Comment: Input is missing a ``` '```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation is complex since your `pattern` and `vector` varies while doing string matching using `agrepl`. So, here I come up with solution which is quite tricky but does the job very well.

```
element_counter = list()
for (i in 1:length(SampleDF$Initial)) {
  if (length(strsplit(as.character(SampleDF$Initial[i]), ",")[[1]]) > 1) {
    element_counter[[i]] <- length(as.character(SampleDF$Post[i])) - sum(agrepl(as.character(SampleDF$Post[i]),strsplit(as.character(SampleDF$Initial[i]), ",")[[1]]))
  }   else { 
    element_counter[[i]] <- length(strsplit(as.character(SampleDF$Post[i]), ",")[[1]]) - sum(agrepl(SampleDF$Initial[i], strsplit(as.character(SampleDF$Post[i]), ",")[[1]]))
  }
}

SampleDF$Type <- unlist(element_counter) 


## SampleDF
#   Group  ID   Initial             Post  Type
#1     0   2  F28D,G06F             G06F    0
#2     0   2       F24J             H02G    1
#3     1   3       G01N   F23C,H02G,G01N    2
```

Answer (score 1):

I split the process into two steps, finding rows with new values, and then finding rows with *only* new values. Adding those two logical vectors together will create types. The only caveat is that the type definitions are a little different then your question definitions. `0` indicates no new measures, `1` indicates that there are new and pre-existing measures, and `2` indicates that there are only pre-existing measures.

```
# This approach needs character columns not strings, so stringsAsFactors = FALSE
SampleDF<-data.frame(Group=c(0,0,1),ID=c(2,2,3),
                     Initial=c('F28D,G06F','F24J' ,'G01N'), 
                               Post=c('G06F','H02G','F23C,H02G,G01N'),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Identify rows where there are new occurrences in Post that are not present in Initial
SampleDF$anyNewOccurrences <- 
  mapply(FUN = function(pattern, x){
    any(!grepl(pattern, x))}, 
    pattern = gsub("," , "|", SampleDF$Initial), 
    x = strsplit(SampleDF$Post, ","))

# Identify rows where there are only new occurences (no repeated values from Initial)
SampleDF$onlyNewOccurrences <- 
  mapply(FUN = function(pattern, x){
    all(!grepl(pattern, x))}, 
    pattern = gsub("," , "|", SampleDF$Initial), 
    x = strsplit(SampleDF$Post, ","))

# Add the two value to gether to create a type code
SampleDF$Type <- SampleDF$onlyNewOccurrences + SampleDF$anyNewOccurrences
```